# AWS EC2 Interminent UnknownHostException when trying to connect to RDS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, playframework, amazon-ec2, dns

I am runnung Java Play on an ec2. When I started up my Play on prod, everything works great. However, after running it about a day, I will start seeing UnknownHostException when connecting to RDS instance. This prevents any transaction between ec2 and rds. If I restart the app again, it works fine again.

I already checked the connection pool and I am pretty sure it works fine. Also, I already tested this with networkaddress.cache.ttl = 0 and networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl = 0. However, I am still getting the error.

Anyone has thoughts on this?

Comment: We've seen ``UnknownHostException`` errors pop up on one (only one specific) instance as well, but they only appear intermittently and fix themselves within a minute or so — no action required from our side. However, for us this isn't limited to RDS, but also happens to connections within the same AWS region

Comment: Happens to me from time to time as well.

Comment: It did not fix themselves in my case. I ended stopping and starting back my ec2 instance and it fixed it permanently. My guess is it got assigned to a new (better configured) ec2 instance when I starting it back up

Answer (score 0):

Just moving this to an answer from the comments. This was fixed by stopping the EC2 instance and then restarting it. After which, the error was not seen again.

> It did not fix itself in my case. I ended stopping/starting my ec2 instance and this fixed it permanently. My guess is that it got assigned to another (better configured) ec2 instance when I starting it back up.

What happens when you [do this](https://alestic.com/2011/09/ec2-reboot-stop-start/).

> - New internal IP address, though could randomly be the same. [VPC instances keep same internal IP addresses through stop/start.]
> - New external IP address (though could randomly be the same).
> - If an Elastic IP address was associated with the instance before it was stopped, then you’ll need to re-associate it after the start.
>     [VPC instances keep Elastic IP addresses associated through
>     stop/start.]
> - Any contents on the instance’s former ephemeral storage were wiped and you are given fresh ephemeral storage (often mounted as /mnt).
> - You can leave an instance stopped for as long as you like and not get charged for run time (though you do get charged at a much lower
>     rate for the EBS volume storage). See the next point.
> - A fresh billing hour is started for the instance when you start it again. E.g., if you start a new instance and then stop/start it 3
>     times within the first 60 minutes, you’ll get charged for 4 hours
>     instead of 1.
> - There is a small chance that EC2 will not have available slots of the correct instance type to run your instance when you want to start
>     it again. I’ve had this happen and temporarily switched to a
>     different, available instance type to get it running again.